# Delphi - Interfaces and overload directive

Tags: delphi, oop, interface

I'm a little bit confused on interfaces in Delphi, so I'm asking you about this. An interface can be 'associated' with an abstract class. (It does not implement the methods declared on it.) All the methods declared on it are implemented in the class/classes which is/are implementing the interface.

So, why then is it allowed to have the overload directive on the method declaration of an interface?

```
type 
 IFoo = interface
  function Test : String; overload;
 end;
```

Compiler is quiet on this.

Comment: -1. I don't understand what your first two statements about interfaces have to do with your question. Yes, interfaces are associated with classes, and yes, the class implements the interface's methods. Why do you think either of those is relevant to the use of `overload` on an interface method? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Further more, what do you mean with "visibility operators"?

Comment: I hope the question is more clear now.

Comment: @RBA: Why in the world should you *not* be allowed to use overloaded methods?

Comment: @Andreas, reading his comment to da-softs answer, he might have benn confused by overload and override.

Comment: No, RBA, your edits haven't addressed my confusion at all. Maybe you're confused about what the `overload` directive means. Include *your* understanding of that directive, and then we'll understand why you're confused about its usage on an interface method. Maybe then we'll also understand why you think that classes have anything to do with it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. `overloaded` allows to have few the same named methods, but with different parameter sets, in a single class / interface.
2. Your interface has `Test` method. With this single method there is no need for `overloaded`. But you can introduce, if you need, additional `Test` methods with differrent parameter sets.
3. Probably you are thinking about `override` directive ...

Comment: override directive can not be placed in a method declaration on a interface. +1 for the answer